# How to trigger auto generation of report based on change in value of an entry in SQL DB?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2014

I have a requirement where report needs to be auto generated in SSRS 2014 whenever an entry in a particular table is modified. Is there any means to achieve this?
For example, below mentioned snippet is my table. Whenever day_status is changed from Open 'O' to Close 'C', report needs to be generated.[Table in my DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIyxp.png)

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is setup a subscription for the report and then setup a trigger on your table to run this report subscription on the status change.

Run this to find out subscription job name

```
SELECT
sj.[name] AS [Job Name],
rs.SubscriptionID,
c.[Name] AS [Report Name],
c.[Path],
su.Description,
su.EventType,
su.LastStatus,
su.LastRunTime,
c.Parameter,*

FROM msdb..sysjobs AS sj 

INNER JOIN ReportServer..ReportSchedule AS rs
ON sj.[name] = CAST(rs.ScheduleID AS NVARCHAR(128)) 

INNER JOIN ReportServer..Subscriptions AS su
ON rs.SubscriptionID = su.SubscriptionID

INNER JOIN ReportServer..[Catalog] c
ON su.Report_OID = c.ItemID


where c.[Name]  like '%your report%'
```

you can use the job name from above to trigger the subscription like this :

```
USE [msdb]
EXEC sp_start_job @job_name = 'the GUID of the Job from the above query'
```

you can wrap this in a stored procedure and use it as part of your trigger

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Will use this and let you know